# How to use binding in a label in code behind

Tags: xamarin, binding, label, code-behind

I want to display a binding field in a label. It's easy in XAML but how to do it in code-behind? In XAML,

```
<Label Text="{Binding LastName}"   Style="{StaticResource MyLabel}"/>.
```

In my code behind, I have tried:

```
Label ln = new Label();
ln.BindingContext = "ContactsModel";
ln.SetBinding = "LastName";
```

which does not work and I have no clue how to set the Style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [Basic Binding documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings), then it clearly states that to bind a view you have to.

1. Specify a BindingContext
2. Use the `SetBinding` method to specify the target property to be bound to which ViewModel source property.

The BindingContext may be inferred from the parent element and does not always have to be specified, but your binding should look more like:

```
var label = new Label();
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "LastName");
```

This will bind the `Text` property on the label to `LastName` in the ViewModel.